# Is it possible to have both libav and ffmpeg installed and running on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, vlc, ffmpeg, clementine, libav

I want to use Clementine but it needs `ffmpeg` to be installed if I want to play `.ape` files from it.

On the other way, I still want to have VLC up and running, and I understand that VLC does no longer use `ffmpeg`, but `libav`. (by the way, VLC plays all audio formats I have, including `.ape` files).

So, my question is: if I install `ffmpeg`, will `libav` still be operational (thus allowing me to use VLC), or will it override libav functionality, thus causing VLC to fail?

The reason I'm asking this here instead of simply trying to install `ffmpeg` is because the last time I installed it VLC stoped working and I only could get it working again reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 14.04, `clementine` is still using the gstreamer0.10 plugins and since **ape** support is provided by the ffmpeg plugin you need to set up the following PPA to play **ape** files:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

I tested both vlc and clementine at the same time using this [sample file](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Audio/Lossless_WAV_Compression/Sample_APE_File.asp) (sh3.ape) and it works flawlessly:

[image]